# question marks in sinatra get method

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am trying to use a question mark in one of my url's but sinatra/ruby is interpreting it as the regex character that makes precedings optional. Is there any way to allow actual ? in your get methods? I have tried \? and [?] but they didn't work. Here is the begining of my get method:

```
get '/group?groupid=:groupId' do |id|
```

If I go to www.mydomain.com/group?groupid=1 I get an error but it works if I go to www.mydomain.com/groupgroupid=1

Answer (score 8):

The "?" starts the querystring portion of the URL; querystring parameters are accessible via the "params" Hash.

Comment: To clarify, just use:  get '/group' do; params[:groupid]; ...; end

Comment: For "/search?q=abc", use: get '/search' do
  q = params['q']